# Autofac PerRequest WebApi 2 + Owin

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

Trying to implement autofac with my WebApi ... but having some issues with lifetime for my objects...

My startup webapi class:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();

    container.RegisterType<MyConcreteClass>().As<IMyInterface>().InstancePerRequest();

    var container = builder.Build();

    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);


    var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);


    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

But not works

**Unable to resolve the type 'IMyInterface' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
- IMyInterface**

**Details ---> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.**

**If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself. (See inner exception for details.)**

Removing this part **.InstancePerRequest();** , then works, but the object is not disposing.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem lies with the following code:

```
var csl = new AutofacServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => csl);
```

The error message indicates you *must* resolve dependencies using the dependency resolver, but this is bypassing that and using the container itself.

> On a side note, using a [service locator is anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). You should be injecting dependencies into your controllers and other MVC extension points rather than using this approach.